# Summation Notation of i = 0 to N

Tags: summation

How do I compute the following $$ \sum_{i=0}^N 1 $$

If it were i instead of 1 then I would then have 0 + 1 + 2 ... + N. But, not sure how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^N1=\underbrace{1+1+\ldots+1}_{N+1\text{ times}}=N+1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $\sum_{i=0}^Nf(i)=f(0)+\cdots+f(N)$, but in this case $f$ is the constant function $1$, so the sum is $N+1$. It's important to note the minimum $i$ is $0$ rather than $1$, to avoid an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Answer (score 0):

I claim $\sum_{i=0}^N 1=N+1,$ which I will prove through [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). When $N=0,$ $\sum_{i=0}^0 1=1=1+0.$ Now, assume the statement for $N=k.$ When $N=k+1,$ we have, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Formal_definition), $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}1=(\sum_{i=0}^k 1)+1.$ Now, by our inductive assumption, we have $\sum_{i=0}^k 1=k+1,$ so the sum becomes $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}1=(k+1)+1,$ thus proving the statement.